# SFML getPosition in if statement

Tags: c++, sfml

I need something like this, but I have no idea how to do it.

```
sprite.move(0, 0.4 * time.asMiliseconds());
if (sprite.getPosition <= *bottom of the screen*)
{
    sprite.setPosition(0,0);
}
```

The the sprite is moving down, but when it goes of the screen, It needs to spawn back up top. I thought a simple if statement would do the job, but it doesn't. I don't know what the output is from .getPosition.

Writing it to the console isn't working aswell so I have no idea what to do.

```
std::cout << sprite.getPosition() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `<=` operator to compare `sf::Vector2<T>` -- mathematically that would be meaningless.

What you want to do is compare its components (x and y).

If you just want to compare the y component to check if your object is below the "bottom" (whatever that is), you can do something along those lines:

```
if (sprite.getPosition().y <= BOTTOM_Y) {
    ...
```

Note that there is no `<<` operator too. You can define your own if you need but this is not part of SFML's job to be text-friendly and provide such operation.